# Var recalculation after content change

Tags: kotlin

I just started learning Kotlin and could not get one thing:

I have a variable that is based on some other variables (for example "A" and "B"). Is there an easy way to recalculate the resulted variable after i change var "A" or "B"?
As i understood, i can just repeat the code for "result" again, but is there an easier way? i think in some cases the code could be quite long...

Example is below:

```
var valueA = 9
var valueB = 10
var result = valueA*valueB
println(result)

valueA = 15
```

"A" is changed, but if i write "println(result)" right now, var "result" will not be recalculated and will stay = 90

```
result = valueA*valueB
println(result)
```

only after i write the same code for "result" again, the output is recalculated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how variables work. When you store something in them it will be how you put it in at the moment. If you want a dynamic result use a function instead:

```
fun result() = valueA * valueB
```

and then print like

```
println(result())
```

If they are class variables (properties) you actually can use variables but then you need to define it with a getter like this for example:

```
val result get() = valueA * valueB
```

Comment: i did not learn the funcitons yet. i checked and now it works. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If `valueA` and `valueB` are in a declaration scope, e.g. in a class/object declaration, you can declare a function or a property with a getter, and compute `valueA * valueB`, like in Ivo's answer.

If `valueA` and `valueB` are in a statement scope, e.g. in a function/lambda's scope (which they look like they are, judging by the fact that you are calling `println` right after), you cannot declare a property with a getter, but you can still declare functions.

If you don't like the `()` syntax when calling a function, I offer a third solution - [property delegates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html). This works in both kinds of scopes.

First, make the function type `() -> T` a property delegate:

```
operator fun <T> (() -> T).getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = this()
```

Then declare `result` as:

```
val result by { valueA * valueB }
// then whenever you use "result", it will compute valueA * valueB!
```

Note that `result` becomes a `val`. You cannot change its definition as "valueA times valueB" after this.

Note that this could be breaking [the principe of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). Some might be quite surprised by this.

You also might want to go for something like this instead:

```
val result by AutomaticComputation { valueA*valueB }

// ...

class AutomaticComputation<T>(val compute: () -> T) {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T = compute()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always have a bit of fun with `Delegates.observable()`
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/observable.html

Example

```
var valueA by Delegates.observable(0) { _, _, _ ->
    calculateValueC()
}
var valueB by Delegates.observable(0) { _, _, _ ->
    calculateValueC()
}

var valueC: Int = 0

fun calculateValueC() {
    valueC = valueA + valueB
    println(valueC)
}

valueA = 5
valueB = 5
```

This would produce the output

```
5
10
```